# Database query with notExists

Tags: 7, database

I can't figure out how to select all aid's from the areas table that do not exist in the field_data_field_area_parent table.

It almost works, except it returns Windy Ridge with an "aid" of "11".   I am guessing that this is because "IN" is the same as "ANY", and the number "1" is in the subquery results.

How can I use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`?

```
function verb_get_parent_areas () {
  $query = db_select('areas', 'a');
  $query->distinct();
  $query->fields('a',array('name','aid','parent','latitude','longitude','description'));
  $subquery = db_select('field_data_field_area_parent', 'p');
  $subquery->fields('p', array('entity_id'));
  $query->condition('a.aid', $subquery, 'NOT IN');

  $result = $query->execute();
  while ($record = $result->fetchAll()) {       
    $areas = drupal_json_encode($record);
  }

  return $areas;
  exit;
}
```

I've thought of trying this, but it returns nothing.

```
function verb_get_parent_areas () {
  $query = db_select('areas', 'a');
  $query->distinct();
  $query->fields('a',array('name','aid','parent','latitude','longitude','description'));
  $subquery = db_select('field_data_field_area_parent', 'p');
  $subquery->fields('p', array('entity_id'));
  $query->notExists($subquery);

  $result = $query->execute();
  while ($record = $result->fetchAll()) {       
    $areas = drupal_json_encode($record);
  }

  return $areas;
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Output your query and arguements to get more insight into what Drupal is doing: drupal_set_message($query->__toString());
drupal_set_message(print_r($query->arguments(),true));

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to write [Dynamic queries](https://drupal.org/node/310075). We generally write queries in phpmyadmin or mysql command prompt and then convert them to D7 style or dynamic queries using [Query coder](https://drupal.org/project/query_coder) module.

For example, as per your question, you want to find out all those records in child table which don't exist in parent table.

So D6 style query,

```
db_query("SELECT c.* FROM {child} c LEFT JOIN {parent} p ON c.p_id = p.p_id WHERE p.p_id IS NULL");
```

after converting to D7 style query using query coder module would look like,

```
$query = db_select('child', 'c');
$query->fields('c', array('*'));
$query->leftJoin('parent', 'p', 'c.p_id = p.p_id');
$query->isNull('p.p_id');
$result = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried out `drupal_write_record()` function? if no then see below link,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825337/help-with-db-query-in-drupal-if-exists-update-else-insert

This may helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: Chandresh,thanks for your reply, but if I'm not mistaken, drupal_write_record is for updating the database.  I am only trying to query the database to output in JSON.

Comment: ok..i'll get back to you again with solutions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, turns out that my query with  'NOT IN' was actually correct, my data in the database was wrong.  I can't believe that I've been working on this for two days and the problem was with my data.

Comment: ok..great. you can also use: **$query->condition('', $subquery, 'EXISTS');**